# within JSF, how to get the real request url

Tags: jsf, request

everyone:

I'm using jsf to do my work.now i want to filter some request,so i need to get the real request url in my filter.

But i don't know how to get the real request url,for example,there is a "commandlink" with a action="#{backBean.test} in my test.xhtml page,now i want to filter the method test,how can i realise it?

i tried to get the request url with HttpServletRequest,but i just got the "test.xhtml" and faild to get the test method...

the following code is part of my filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    String reqUrl = req.getRequestURI();
    String willFilterUrl = reqUrl.substring(reqUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, reqUrl.length());
    String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
    if("order_confirm.xhtml".equals(willFilterUrl)) {
        resp.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/pause_1.xhtml");
        return;
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to listen on a specific request URL, or do you want to listen on a specific backing bean method? This is quite different. The filter does only the former, not the latter, while you seem to want the latter. Nonetheless, this all looks very fishy and stongly feels a XY-problem. Take a step back, which problem exactly are you trying to solve which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution?

Comment: dear BalusC,thanks for your reply...You know,if we use Spring MVC that I can get the request method of RequestMapping.Even though it's just a ajax request....For me,I want to get the same as RequestMapping...For example,in JSF,<h:commondButton action="#{backBean.test}"/>,and now,i don't want to let anyone to request the method "test" ,and i don't want to code in the method "test",I want to do it in my Filter or another way,besides code in the method 'test"....how can i do that....sorry for my pool english...thanks.

Comment: Huh? Are you now mixing HTTP request methods with Java class methods? Anyway, please tell about your XY problem. This all starts to become nonsense. The logic in your filter does not match the requirement at all. You seem to be attempting to figure out the action method's navigation outcome return value.

Comment: That is to say, I should do it in my action method rather than the other way?

Comment: Depends on the X of your XY problem.

Comment: @BalusC, Perhaps I knew that I can't filter the action method in filter.Because the filter is earlier than the facescontext,I will try in another way....Thanks for your help.Good luck.